# How to visualize average response time of all requests

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a metric `http_request_duration_seconds` which is a histogram based on Action,

> http_request_duration_seconds The duration of HTTP requests processed
>   by an ASP.NET Core application. TYPE http_request_duration_seconds
>   histogram

which data is :

```
http_request_duration_seconds_sum{code="200",method="GET",controller="Player",action="Load"} 0.4301564
http_request_duration_seconds_count{code="200",method="GET",controller="Player",action="Load"} 1
http_request_duration_seconds_sum{code="200",method="POST",controller="Auth",action="Token"} 0.2790333
http_request_duration_seconds_count{code="200",method="POST",controller="Auth",action="Token"} 1
```

Now in Grafana, I want to visualize the average of response time of all my actions in a specified time frame for example 5 minutes.

In this example data, my desired output for this moment should be `(0.43 + 0.27) / ( 1 + 1)`

What is the `promql` query to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

`sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum[5m])) / sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count[5m]))`

See [Prometheus docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/) for more details.